# Merging of tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

More and more tags are being created, and already there is a pair that I think should be merged:

- [overclock](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overclock) (1 question)
- [overclocking](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overclocking) (1 question)

These could be merged into either one of them, I'm not sure which one of them is the best.

I realize that this raises another issue. As the site is in a very early stage, should tags be merged already, or should the questions simply be edited?

Comment: I just edited the one question tagged with [tag:overclock] to use [tag:overclocking].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd vote for changing them both to "overclocking" (and at this stage, they might as well be edited rather than going through the process of creating a synonym.)

Comment: I don't think anyone can create synonyms yet?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Good point, I believe you need over 1k reputation to do that... editing it is!